# Finish activity onPause but still be in backstack?

Tags: android-activity, android, back-stack

I'm trying to minimize memory usage in my app, and one of the things I'm doing is calling finish() in the onPause method (which I know is not the best way to do things). For the most part, it seems to be working well, but when the user clicks the back button from the next activity, it logically skips over the finished activity and goes back further. Is it possible to have that activity in the back stack and just get recreated if the user presses back?

Comment: Why do you really need it? Do you have problems with `OutOfMemoryError`? `Activity` alone occupies at most several kilobytes of memory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. This conclusion comes from [the task and backstack documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html) as well as the [activity documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) and a general understanding of how a [stack data structure](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_%28abstract_data_type%29) works.

A stack data strucure only has 2 possible operations push/put, which adds something to the collection, and pop, which removes it. Stacks folow a last in first out model, or LIFO, where by last thing added - in your case an activity - is the first thing removed when pop is called.

Within the android lifecycle activities are generally popped from the stack when the back button is pressed. At that point `onDestroy()` is called and the activity is removed (you can verify this by overriding the `onDestroy()` method and logging the results if you want to check). Alternativly you can force `onDestroy()` to be called by calling `finish()` as you are. Finishing an activity effectivly does the same thing as pressing back. The activity is destroyed and must be recreated before it can be added to the stack.

For what you're trying to do the stack would have to incorporate some intermediate state in which an activity does not exist but rather something akin to a reference is held that, when moved to the top, would indicate that the corresponding activity should be recreated. Since this is not how the sack works - it only holds activities - that state cannont exist and so the result you are talking about is not possible.

Answer (score 2):

Your Goal is to **minimize memory** usage,Just make use of **activity life cycle**, You can do this alternative(if you need)

-Just leave **onCreate()** method blank.(only do setContentView(layout))

-Override **onResume()**;

-whatever you were doing in onCreate just copy paste to onResume().

-and In **onPause()**, **Recycle** your all **bitmaps** and set them to null(I think you are using Bitmaps thats why you are very cautious about it ). and **remove** your views.

Now what will happen, when you launch your new activity, **onPause()** would be called. that will remove your all bitmap and views. and when you come back, **onResume()** will be call.(onCreate will not be called). and that will again initialize your view and bitmaps.

Comment: Should I  null all ImageViews? or do ImageViews automatically recycle bitmaps?

Comment: Image view will not recycle bitmap. You have to recycle your bitmap by bitmap.recycle();

Answer (score 1):

No, i don't think that is possible. Once you finish the Activity it's gone. You could, however, implement and handle your own stack. On back pressed, you would just start the closed Activity again.

Comment: Agreed - you could create your own structure which would hold the original order in which activites were added and, maybe through an intent, recreate those which were previously destroyed.

Comment: The problem would be to recreate the exact Activity state. E.g. if the user has entered text in an EditText, you don't want this text to disappear when you come back to this Activity.

Comment: Could you make that happen with savedInstaceState or SharedPreferences?

Comment: You probably could, but you need to save the Bundle somewhere extern. The Activity gets destroyed when you finish it and therefore the Bundle with it.

Comment: Or pass it to a background fragment with no UI. IDK when I'd use something like this but now I just want to make it work lol